# Using partials in mvc from other project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Is that possible to move some partials (*.cshtml) to core classes project and use them in other mvc project ?

Maybe by injecting or using something in _ViewImports ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put them in a Razor Class Library:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class

> Razor views, pages, controllers, page models, Razor components, View components, and data models can be built into a Razor class library (RCL). The RCL can be packaged and reused. Applications can include the RCL and override the views and pages it contains. When a view, partial view, or Razor Page is found in both the web app and the RCL, the Razor markup (.cshtml file) in the web app takes precedence.
>
> ### Create a class library containing Razor UI
>
> - From Visual Studio select Create new a new project.
> - Select Razor Class Library > Next.
> - Name the library (for example, "RazorClassLib"), > Create. To avoid a    file name collision with the generated view library, ensure the
>     library name doesn't end in .Views.
> - Select Support pages and views if you need to support views. By    default, only Razor Pages are supported. Select Create.
>
> The Razor class library (RCL) template defaults to Razor component
>   development by default. The Support pages and views option supports
>   pages and views.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `Areas`. You can find everything about them [on the microsoft docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

The MVC project with the partial views that you want to use needs a structure like this (found on the microsoft docs page, see link above):

[image]

So let's say you want a partial view called `_TestPartial.cshtml` in the Area `Home`. Then you need the following structure:

[image]

Then, in the main project, you reference this new project you created.

Next, you need an extra endpoint in your `startup.cs` file:

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
        name: "Home",
        areaName: "Home",
        pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Finally, you can use this Partial in your views like so:

```
<div>@await Html.PartialAsync("/Areas/Home/Views/Home/_TestPartial.cshtml")</div>
```

You can now also redirect to controller actions in these areas like this:

```cs
return RedirectToAction("Index","Home",new { area = "Home "});
```